# Triggers with DMS CDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, cdc, aws-dms

AWS DMS task to replicate the data from Oracle(A) to PostgreSQL(B) and dms from PostgreSQL(B) to Oracle(C). Once the data is loaded to Target (B) I need to have trigger in place to capture date time and actions like (I,U,D) . Is it advisable to have trigger in place ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to include Postgres in between Oracle(A) and (C) but yes this is possible without DB Triggers.
You can create task to move data+CDC from A to B then create a new DMS task from B to C. This B to C task is again Full load /+ CDC as per your requirement. So DMS will handle it internally. No need to add manual DB triggers.